# Use of Gibbs-Helmholtz Equation to Calculate Electrochemical Work

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry

When we derive the expression $\mathrm{d}G=V\mathrm{d}P-S\mathrm{d}T$, if my understanding is correct, we do not consider the term representing useful (non-PV) work. Based on this expression, we conclude $$\left(\frac{\delta G}{\delta P}\right)_T=V$$ and $$\left(\frac{\delta G}{\delta T}\right)_P=-S$$
Further, we use these functions when deriving a relation for the EMF of a cell with temperature, obtaining the result
$$E_{cell}=\frac{-\Delta H}{nF}+T\left(\frac{\delta E_{cell}}{\delta T}\right)_P $$
My confusion arises from the fact that while deriving the first two results, we neglected the useful work term, but used the result in a process where we are concerned with the non-PV work. Where am I going wrong in my understanding?

Comment: Chem+Math formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/) / [Upright vs Italics](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) // MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: The equation you wrote for dG is for a pure component, not a mixture of reacting components.

Comment: @Chet Miller could you please elaborate a bit on this? I would be very grateful as I'm really struggling with this concept, so if you could write out an answer it would really help me out

Comment: For a mixture, $$dG=-SdT+VdP+\sum \mu_jdN_j{}$$ where $\mu_j$ is the chemical potential (Partial molar free energy) of the j'ta species and $N_j$ is change in the number of moles of the j'ta species

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's clear now